# Facebook marketing api acess token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am trying to get my `( OWN )` ad accounts data using facebook `insights api`. the very first step is getting `access token`. until now i was using access token generated by `graph api explorer` by extending it lifetime manually. now what is the programmatic way of getting access token. i have referred this documntation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

This is only possible when i am using some sort of front-end or browser interface to open up `login dialog` but i am using a `python script`. its not possible to open up the login dialog. ho do i get my access token .

as far as i understand login dialog popu up when using `user access token`. i think i need to use `app access token` . are both same?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the step here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens
You can get the access token through the sample code

But reminded that because this request uses your app secret, it must never be made in client-side code or in an app binary that could be decompiled.